# Android - Radio button selections are not being registered

Tags: android

I am trying to use radio buttons but they aren't working.  I've got the toast in there at the moment purely for debugging, and it never appears.  There seems to be various ways to use them so perhaps I'm just using a poor method.  Any advice on what I've done wrong would be amazing.

```
final RadioButton rbSDR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbSDR);
final RadioButton rbMM = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMM);
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
//int checkedRadioButtonID = radGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {

   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checked",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

   switch (id) {
   case -1:
       rbMM.setChecked(false);
       rbSDR.setChecked(false);
     break;
   case R.id.rbSDR:
       rbMM.setChecked(false);
     break;
   case R.id.rbMM:
       rbSDR.setChecked(false);
     break;
   default:
     break;
   }

});
```

EDIT:
Apparently the issue was that I had a linear layout WITHIN the radio button group.  Now to figure out how to put the buttons side by side...

Answer (score 0):

the id will always return -1 only. Try the following edited code,

```
final RadioButton rbSDR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbSDR);
rbSDR.setId(R.id.rbSDR);
final RadioButton rbMM = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMM);
rbMM.setId(R.id.rbMM);
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
//int checkedRadioButtonID = radGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {

   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checked",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

   switch (id) {
   case -1:
       rbMM.setChecked(false);
       rbSDR.setChecked(false);
     break;
   case R.id.rbSDR:
       rbMM.setChecked(false);
     break;
   case R.id.rbMM:
       rbSDR.setChecked(false);
     break;
   default:
     break;
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

set the listener to radio buttons instead of radio group

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

Use

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
```

Answer (score 0):

To put the `radio buttons` side-by-side, add this to the `XML properties`:

`android:orientation="horizontal"`